# InflateException on using softkeyboard layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

I am using post [SoftKeyBoardListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)  and create a custom class but when I calling it in my activity class, so getting an exception

as

```
04-01 15:45:28.105: E/AndroidRuntime(21534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.Settings}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard

04-01 15:45:28.105: E/AndroidRuntime(21534):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white" >


    </LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard>
```

I also defined in Manifest as below

```
<activity
        android:name="mypackage.Settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Calling it onCreate of Activity as

```
LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard mainLayout = (LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard)findViewById(R.id.settings);
         mainLayout.setListener(this);
```

and also implemented `LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard.Listener` aswell.

Therefore how to reference custom class which extends LinearLayout to Activity for Keyboard show/hide listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide full class name in layout declaration :

```
<your.package.name.LinearLayoutThatDetectsSoftKeyboard
... your layout params
/>
```